# Show that a reference frame exists where the spatial separation is zero.

Tags: special-relativity

### question

I am trying to show that if the *Lorentz Invariant Interval* is positive
$$c^2 \Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2>0$$
then there exists a reference frame $S^{'}$ where $\Delta x^{'}=0$.

### context

consider a pair of reference frames $S$ and $S^{'}$.

[image]

$S^{'}$ is sliding away from $S$ at constant velocity $v$ along a common $x$, $x^{'}$ axis.

Consider two events $E1$ and $E2$.

From the perspective of an observer in $S$, $E1$ happens at $(x_{1},t_{1})$ and $E2$ happens at $(x_{2},t_{2})$.

From the perspective of an observer in $S^{'}$, $E1$ happens at $(x^{'}_{1},t^{'}_{1})$ and $E2$ happens at $(x^{'}_{2},t^{'}_{2})$.

We can relate the events in the two reference frames using the Lorentz transformations.

$$x^{'}=\gamma(x- v t)$$
$$t^{'}=\gamma(t- \frac{v}{c^2} t)$$

where as usual:
$\gamma = (1- \frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

The differences between the events can be denoted.

$$\Delta x = x_2 -x_1$$
$$\Delta t = t_2 -t_1$$
$$\Delta x^{'} = x^{'}_2 -x^{'}_1$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = t^{'}_2 -t^{'}_1$$

Using the Lorentz transformations we are able to express the space and time separations between the events in terms of the coordinates in the first reference frame and $v$ the speed of $S^{'}$ relative to $S$.
$$\Delta x^{'} = \gamma (\Delta x - v \Delta t)$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = \gamma (\Delta t - \frac{v}{c^2}\Delta x)$$

## Attempt 1.

So my task is prove that a reference frame exists where $\Delta x^{'}=0$.

I guess I can do this by defining such a reference frame.
How do I define a reference frame?

I guess I can define a reference frame $S^{'}$ by choosing its velocity $v$.
(This is the velocity relative to the other reference frame).

I see that I could choose $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} $.
If I plug this $v$ into $\Delta x^{'} = \gamma (\Delta x - v \Delta t)$. Then I get:
$$\Delta x^{'} = \gamma (\Delta x - v \Delta t)$$
$$\Delta x^{'} = \gamma (\Delta x - \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} \Delta t)$$
$$\Delta x^{'} = 0$$

But this is nothing to do with the *Lorentz Invariant Interval* being positive??

Help appreciated!

> How do I show that the positive-ness of the *Lorentz Invariant Interval* implies that there exists a reference frame $S^{'}$ with $\Delta x^{'}=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorentz transformation works only if $|v|<c$. Otherwise, $\gamma$ becomes complex.

However, when $c^2\Delta t^2 -\Delta x^2 \le 0$, then $v^2=\frac{\Delta x^2}{\Delta t^2}\ge c^2$ or $|v|\ge c$.